# How to remove all foreign characters SAS

Tags: sas

I have been dealing with this problem all day today, so far I tried below but it is still causing error. The error shows

*Last Name field may only contain alphabetic characters, hyphens, or apostrophes. Please remove all foreign characters and resubmit.*

```
data APPLIED_GRAD1;
set APPLIED_GRAD;
last_name=compress(last_name,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|[]{};:',.<>?/ " , "kis");
pos_notalpha = notalpha ( TRIMN ( last_name )) ;

keep  last_name;
 run;

data APPLIED_GRAD2;
set APPLIED_GRAD1;
where pos_notalpha=0;
run;
```

Is anything I can do anything else to remove all foreign Characters?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you keeping # $ etc if the rules is that only hyphens or apostrophes are allowed?  The 's' modifier includes other characters than just space.

Comment: Depends on alphabetic characters definition your list not includes ÄÖÜßâ and so on without that names maybe wrong

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can clean specific ASCII chars from a string.  Define an FCMP function:

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.funcs;

  function clean(iField $) $200;  
    bad_char_list = byte( 0) || byte( 1) || byte( 2) || byte( 3) || byte( 4) || byte( 5) || byte( 6) || byte( 7) || byte( 8) || byte( 9) || 
                    byte(10) || byte(11) || byte(12) || byte(13) || byte(14) || byte(15) || byte(16) || byte(17) || byte(18) || byte(19) || 
                    byte(20) || byte(21) || byte(22) || byte(23) || byte(24) || byte(25) || byte(26) || byte(27) || byte(28) || byte(29) || 
                    byte(30) || byte(31) || 
                    byte(127) 
                    ;  
    iCleaned = translate(iField," ",bad_char_list);
    return (iCleaned );
  endsub;

run;
```

Example Usage - Cleaning line breaks prior to exporting to CSV:

```
data x;
 length employer $200;

 employer = cats("blah",byte(10),"diblah");
 employer = clean(employer);
run;

proc export data=x
             outfile="d:\test.csv"
             dbms=csv
             replace;
run;
```

Note - This function is pretty slow if you have a very large dataset and/or are running against many fields.  If you are targeting very specific bad characters (for example those that may affect CSV integrity) then you may want to reduce the character list to just bytes 9/10/13.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways

**Regular expression**

Use `PRXCHANGE` with a regular expression pattern containing a bracketed NOT (`^`) character class specifying which non-matching characters are to be replaced with nothing (`//`).  The literal characters dash (`-`) and apostrophe (`'`) need to be escaped with backslash (`\`)

```
lastname = prxchange("s/[^A-Za-z\-\']//", -1, lastname);
```

**Compress with list of characters to keep**

The `compress` function using the third parameter form to specify the compress option `K` to mean keep instead of remove.

```
lastname = compress(lastname, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-'", 'K');
```